# atributo en campo timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Buen dia compañeros,

Hoy me encuentro diseñando un diagrama erm en workbench y no se como colocar una columna que guarde la fecha de actualizacion con cada registro.

En caso practico, yo quiero hacer un sistema de historias clínicas, donde se establezca una columna de fecha de creación y otra de fecha de modificación, donde la creación sea la fecha automática del momento del registro, y la fecha de modificación guarde la ultima fecha en que el registro fue modificado.

Cosa de que el medico 1 cree una nueva nota en la historia clínica el 1 de octubre del 2018 y que posteriormente ese registro haya sido modificado, y la fecha de dicho registro fue el 15 de diciembre de 2018.

Estoy haciendo las tablas mediante tablas de erm y no se donde meterme para hacer eso...

[image: Opciones para timestamp en workbench]

Aquí encontré la opción de colocar un timestamp pero desafortunadamente el parametro debe contener algo donde estan los asteriscos y no tengo la mas minima idea. He intentado con el formato colocando "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" pero me sale error.

[image: Error al introducir parametro YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:DD]

**Pregunta**

**¿Que debo hacer para lograr mi cometido?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Declara la columna `Historias_Clinicascol` como `TIMESTAMP` pero sin los paréntesis
- En la última columna que se llama **Default/Expression** puedes asignar por ejemplo la función `NOW()`, para indicar que si la columna no se le asigna un valor tenga un valor por defecto sea la fecha y hora actual con la que se rellene ese registro

Debería verse de este modo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Si por ejemplo esta declaración la hicieras a nivel de consola, con un `DESCRIBE` se vería de este modo:

Muestra:

```
Field   Type        Null    Key Default             Extra
fecha   timestamp   YES     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT_GENERATED
```

Ahora si lo que deseas es pasar un valor específico, lo que espera obtener en los paréntesis es un número entero entre 1 a 10, si excedes el límite vas a tener un error como este:

> Too-big precision 16 specified for 'fecha'. Maximum is 10.

Mi mejor recomendación toma la opción que menciono al inicio.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ha sido perfecto!